# Add a Keyboard Layout in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to set up [Mirrorboard](http://blog.xkcd.com/2007/08/14/mirrorboard-a-one-handed-keyboard-layout-for-the-lazy/) on my computer running 14.04 LTS.  I downloaded the [layout file](http://xkcd.com/mirrorboard.xkb), but have no idea how to set this as my keyboard layout.  I have it placed in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols right now, but I don't even know if that's right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I placed the file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.  I also renamed the file `mb`.

Then, I opened a terminal and typed in the following:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
```

Followed by

```
xkbcomp mb $DISPLAY 2>/dev/null
```

And I've got it working well.

Comment: If you want to add it so that you can select it with the normal interfaces, maybe http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ can help. (It's different, but probably you can adapt it)